# Coset bijection for non-abelian groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

From a [Stanford course on Representation Theory](http://sporadic.stanford.edu/bump/group/gind1_1.html):

> Exercise 1.1.6: In the last proof, if we said that $xH\mapsto Hx$ is a bijection between the set of left cosets and the set of right cosets, we would be lying. What is wrong with this statement?

I know that in general $xH \neq Hx$, but saying that there is a bijection between the two is a weaker statement. Why would the map $xH \rightarrow Hx$ fail to be a bijection?

Comment: Use `$\mapsto$` for $\mapsto$.

Comment: What *is* true is that $$xH=yH \iff y^{-1}xH = H \iff y^{-1}x \in H \iff y^{-1}(x^{-1})^{-1} \in H$$ $$\iff y^{-1} \in H x^{-1} \iff H y^{-1}=H x^{-1}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that this map is not well-defined.  Saying you map $xH$ to $Hx$ involves picking a particular representative $x$ of the coset $xH$, and different representatives can give you different results: $xH=yH$ does not necessarily imply $Hx=Hy$.  Indeed, $xH=yH$ iff $y^{-1}x\in H$ and $Hx=Hy$ iff $xy^{-1}\in H$, and these will typically not be equivalent since $x$ and $y^{-1}$ may not commute.  (For instance, in $S_3$, if you take $x$ to be a $2$-cycle and $y$ to be a $3$-cycle then $xy^{-1}$ and $y^{-1}x$ will be two different $2$-cycles which generate different subgroups.)

Answer (score 2):

You can have $xH = yH$ while $Hx \ne Hy$.

Comment: In other words, the map $xH\mapsto Hx$ is not well-defined; choosing a different representative $x$ can lead to a different right coset.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Indeed. I hoped the OP would draw that conclusion.